# List youtube channels as a back-end process without prompting for username and password using python

Tags: youtube-api

I want run a back-end process to get the list of channels from youtube without prompting for username password.I tried to do so with the following python code.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from apiclient.discovery import build
from optparse import OptionParser

DEVELOPER_KEY = "MY API KEY"
YOUTUBE_API_SERVICE_NAME = "youtube"
YOUTUBE_API_VERSION = "v3"

youtube = build(YOUTUBE_API_SERVICE_NAME, YOUTUBE_API_VERSION,developerKey=DEVELOPER_KEY)

channels_response = youtube.channels().list(
  part="contentDetails",
  managedByMe="true",
  onBehalfOfContentOwner=ownerdetail
).execute()

for channel in channels_response["items"]:
  channel_id = channel["id"]
  channel_title = channel["snippet"]["title"]
  print "Channel details: %s - %s" % channel_id % channel_title
print "Done"
```

When I try to run this code I'm getting  "Access Not Configured"> error in console.

My requirement is to run this successfully without prompting for username and password(since i want it as a back-end process). Any help is this would be really helpful since I'm new to this.

Answer (score 0):

You can do so by getting a refresh token from [OAuth2 Playground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/) and setting it in your youtube object.

[Here it explains a little more.](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/moving_to_oauth#standalone)

[And a step by step video.](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lJjQPaPAfWM)